# Нахождение самого длинного слова в тексте, недочеты алгоритма - Java

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с небольшой проблемой, задача - написать программу, которая ищет самое длинное слово в тексте, вводимого построчно, причем слова могут быть разделены любыми символами, кроме "_". Сама программа удалась, но с большими объемами текста за нужное время не справляется. Прошу помощи с ее оптимизацией или изменения алгоритма работы. Цель - проанализировать текст содержащий **до 500 000 символов менее чем за секунду**.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Start {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "",max = "";
        while (in.hasNextLine()){
            str += " " + in.nextLine();
        }
        String[] strL = new String[90000]; //массив слов
        for (int i = 0; i<strL.length; i++) {
            strL[i] = "";
        }
        for (int i=0,k=0;i<str.length(); i++){
            int chr = str.charAt(i); //номер символа
            if ((chr > 47 && chr < 58) || (chr > 64 && chr < 91 ) || (chr > 96 && chr < 123) || (chr == 95)){
                strL[k] = strL[k]+str.charAt(i); // проверяю, находится ли символ, разделяющий слова, если нет, прибавляю символ к слову, иначе, перехожу к следующему
            }
            else {k++;}
        }
        for (String aStrL : strL) {        //нахожу наибольшее слово
            if (aStrL.length() > max.length()) {
                max = aStrL;
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

*P.S. Первый раз пишу на Stack Overflow, заранее извиняюсь за ошибки и недочеты)*

Comment: Необходимо ли забивать `strL` пустыми строками? Лучше использовать не `String`, а `StringBuilder` или `StringBuffer`. В последнем переборе можно бежать не по всему массиву, а до заранее известного числа вставленных слов. Имхо сортировка, как предложили в ответе, применительно к задаче с такими требованиями - зло

Comment: Вообще не надо заносить слова ни в какой массив. Анализируете посимвольно строку, определяете вы в слове или между ними. Как только определили, что внутри слова, начинаете считать его длину. Как только поняли, что начался промежуток, корректируете текущий максимум.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант такой ( но могут быть косяки с граничными условиями и предполагается что слово не может быть разорвано переносом строки, нужно проверять на реальных данных ):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line, max = "";
    int start = 0;
    while (in.hasNextLine()){
        line = in.nextLine();
        for (int i=0; i<line.length(); i++){
            int chr = line.charAt(i); //номер символа
            if ((chr > 47 && chr < 58) || (chr > 64 && chr < 91 ) || (chr > 96 && chr < 123) || (chr == 95)){
            } else {
                if ( i - start > max.length() ) {
                    max = line.substring( start, i );
                }
                start = i+1;
            }
        }
        start = 0;
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

Comment: Благодарю, я понял смысл, но тесты все-равно какие-то чудеса творят. При вводе только чисел или только подчеркиваний - на выводе пусто. Даже не знаю как это понимать...
Возможно из-за того, что кроме нужных символов, в вводе ничего нет, то есть else ни разу не выполняется, но это предположение.
P.S. Переносов слова через строку - нет.

Comment: Как можно поставить проверку на то, кончилась строка или нет? А то если имеем на ввод: 1 22 333 4444 55555, то на выводе будет 4444 и т.п.

Comment: Я начал добавлять не читаемый символ в конец каждой строки и все заработало, огромное спасибо)

Comment: @КириллПешков Как раз граничные условия - не всё предусмотрел, извиняюсь) А так - всегда пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал вот так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String wordWithMaxLength = "";

while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split("(_|\\s)+");

   Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
   wordWithMaxLength = words[0].length() > wordWithMaxLength.length() ? words[0] : wordWithMaxLength;
}

System.out.println(wordWithMaxLength);
```

Если версия `java` < 8:

```
Arrays.sort(words, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                return Integer.compare(o2.length(), o1.length());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Компилятор ругается на строку Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length, Comparator.reverseOrder()));

Comment: @КириллПешков java 8 нужна

Comment: А вот с этим проблема...
У меня-то java 8ая, а вот на сервере - нет. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: Теперь быстро, но не правильно)
Ввод: 678+23467.89+87909-234_L/43  // Error
Вывод: 678+23467.89+87909-23
Ввод:  Voronezh State University is one of the main universities in Central Russia.
Вывод: universitie 
и т.п.
То есть он проглатывает последнюю букву иногда + игнорирует некоторые символы(

Comment: Я не знаю по каким символам происходит разбиение на слова. В моем ответе основная идея заключается в том, что строку делим на слова. Разбиение происходит на основе регулярного выражения - (_|\\s)+ - нижнее подчеркивание либо символ пробела. задайте указанные символы в регулярке и все будет работать.

Answer (score 0):

На всякий случай альтернативный вариант решения. Умеет корректно работать с русскими буквами. Если словом является набор цифр, то вместо `Character.isLetter()` надо использовать `Character.isLetterOrDigit()` На моей машине сработал быстрее, чем предолженный в ответе. Также, если нет необходимости, можно убрать обработку переноса строки.

```
String getLongestWord(String s){
    //Символ подчеркивания и переноса строки
    final char underLine = '_';
    final char nextLine = '\n';
    //Результирующая строка
    String result = "";
    //Счетчик кол-ва символов переноса
    int nextLines = 0;
    //Флаг наличия данного символа у результирующего слова
    boolean resultHasNextLines = false;
    //Массив символов, в котором ведем поиск
    char[] searchArray = s.toCharArray();
    //Значение индекса начала текущего слова
    int wordStartIndex = 0;
    //Флаг нахождения в слове
    boolean inWord = true;

    //Проходим по всем строкам
    for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        //Если обнаружен символ новой строки, и мы находимся в слове, добавляем счетчик
        if (searchArray[i]==nextLine && inWord)
            nextLines++;
        //Иначе, если текущий символ буква или нижнее подчеркивание
        else if ((Character.isLetter(searchArray[i])||searchArray[i]==underLine)) {
            //Если до этого мы не были в слове
            if (!inWord) {
                //Устанавливаем стартовый индекс, и триггер слова
                wordStartIndex = i;
                inWord = true;
            }
        } else {//Иначе если какой-либо другой символ
            //Если до этого были в слове
            if (inWord) {
                //Получаем длину слова. При этом игнорируем символы перехода на след линию
                final int len = nextLines>0 ? i - wordStartIndex - nextLines : i - wordStartIndex;
                //Если эта длина больше чем предыдущая максимальная
                if (len > result.length()) {
                    //Обновляем результирующую строку
                    result = s.substring(wordStartIndex, i);
                    //Устанавливем триггер символа новой строки для результирующего слова
                    resultHasNextLines = nextLines>0;
                } else nextLines = 0;//Иначе не забываем сбросить счетчик символов новой строки
                inWord = false;
            }
        }
    }

    //Если были символы новой строки убираем их из результата.
    if (resultHasNextLines) result = result.replaceAll(String.valueOf(nextLine),"");

    return result;
}
```